# Clarification on reloading modules

Tags: python, module

Setup - I would like to run a script to process data twice - once on one month of data, and once on a year's worth.  I want to use a boolean variable `longterm`.  `longterm` should load as False, then flip truth values at the bottom of the script, so it runs as True on the second / every other run.

My plan was to put `longterm` in a module.  Python is only supposed to read and load modules once.

> A module can contain executable statements as well as function definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module. They are executed only the first time the module name is encountered in an import statement. [(Documentation on Modules)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

But in fact, `longterm` is reloaded each time, so for each run, it starts as False instead of alternating.  Meanwhile, print statements from the reloaded module *do not* re-appear.  So the module is doing what I would want with the print statement (ignoring it on successive runs), but not with the variable.

*Minimal Example*

**mod.py**

```
longterm = False
print('Setting "longterm" to False.')
```

**nb.ipynb**

```
from mod import *
longterm = not(longterm)
print(longterm)
```

(Run the notebook multiple times.)

Result - The print statement from **mod.py** only appears on the first run.  But the variable `longterm` must be reloaded each run, as it is the same value (True) at the end of each run.

Why does Python do this?  Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: It isn't reloading the module, however, it is re-assigning `mod.x` to the local `x`. But you **never modified `mod.x`**. You simply assigned another value to the local `x`. Note, you *really* should use `from mod import *` in general

Comment: An alternative, try `import mod` then use `longterm = not mod.longterm` (note, don't use needless parentheses with `not`)